# Magento 2: Export Order Shipping Address As Separate Fields

Tags: magento2, orders, csv, export

When I export orders as a `csv` file from Magento 2 admin, the shipping address is exported as a single field in the `csv` file, i.e. there is a column called `"shipping address"` with the entire address in one field.

In order to import the info into a shipping/label printing app, I would like to export the address from Magento as separate fields, so `"street address 1", "street address 2", "city", "region", Postcode"` each as separate columns in the `csv` file.

Anyone know how to do that?